# How can I optimize writing multiple lines of output?

Tags: java

Is there a better solution than writing a `System.out.println` in this way?

```
String nl = System.getProperty("line.separator");

for (k=0; k<=ds.size()-counter-1; k=k+counter){
            System.out.println (metric+" "+ds.get(k)+" "+ds.get(k+2)+" sensor=A cell="+ cellName + nl +
            metric+" "+ds.get(k)+" "+ds.get(k+3)+" sensor=B cell="+ cellName + nl + 
            metric+" "+ds.get(k)+" "+ds.get(k+4)+" sensor=C cell="+ cellName + nl + 
            metric+" "+ds.get(k)+" "+ds.get(k+5)+" sensor=D cell="+ cellName + nl +
            metric+" "+ds.get(k)+" "+ds.get(k+6)+" sensor=E cell="+ cellName + nl + 
            metric+" "+ds.get(k)+" "+ds.get(k+7)+" sensor=F cell="+ cellName + nl + 
            metric+" "+ds.get(k)+" "+ds.get(k+8)+" sensor=G cell="+ cellName + nl + 
            metric+" "+ds.get(k)+" "+ds.get(k+9)+" sensor=H cell="+ cellName + nl +
            metric+" "+ds.get(k)+" "+ds.get(k+10)+" sensor=I cell="+ cellName + nl +    
            metric+" "+ds.get(k)+" "+ds.get(k+11)+" sensor=L cell="+ cellName + nl +    
            metric+" "+ds.get(k)+" "+ds.get(k+12)+" sensor=M cell="+ cellName + nl +
            metric+" "+ds.get(k)+" "+ds.get(k+13)+" sensor=N cell="+ cellName); 
            }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a StringBuilder, append your Strings to the StringBuilder, and then print it in one System.out.println call.

Oh, and you can easily nest two for loops and make your code much more readable.

e.g.,

```
  StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
  Formatter formatter = new Formatter(stringBuilder);
  int maxSomething = 12;
  String template = metric + " %s %s sensor=%c cell=" + cellName + nl;
  for (int i = 0; i < ds.size()-counter-1; i = i + counter) {
     for (int j = 0; j < maxSomething; j++) {
        formatter.format(template, ds.get(i), ds.get(i + j + 2), (char)('A' + j));
     }
  }
  // the toString() below isn't necessary but is present for clarity
  System.out.println(stringBuilder.toString());
  formatter.close();
```

- *Note: code not compiled nor tested.*
- *Note 2: code as written risks trying to extract items beyond the size of the ds list. You will want to set maxSomething based on the size of your ds list*

Comment: @Markviduka: It ***is*** a higher performance solution since printlns are very slow while `StringBuilder#append(...)` is pretty fast. See edit for e.g.,

Comment: +1 for making use of `format` to DRY up the text to be output.